# What is the SyntaxError here in return '<h1>Hello world</h1>' when I try to launch my Flask application?

Tags: python, flask

I am a beginner at Flask and this is my first time trying to run a Flask application. My hello.py code is:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index:
    return '<h1>Hello world</h1>'
```

And after running the program on CMD using the command `python -m flask run`

I got this error

```
SyntaxError
File "C:\Users\91932\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Personal Projects\FLASK Projects\Test\hello.py", line 4
    def index:
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What should I do? Please help.

Comment: You are missing `()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index is a function, needs parenthesis

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>Hello world</h1>'
```